How can I disable Google Maps on Android Auto
I like to use Waze on Android Auto.  I have these issues

Even though I have Waze as the first app and Maps as the last app, Google Maps invariably shows up in the first few apps.
I use Waze all the time,  saying "Hey Google, take me somewhere" works most of the time.
Sometimes it launches Maps instead, even though Waze is already running.
I then say "Hey Google, use Waze to take me somewhere", this works half the time, the other half, it still uses Maps.

This becomes extremely annoying when I am already driving.  I have to pull over and physically reconnect the phone, sometimes I have to manually select Waze from the apps.
Is there a way to permanently remove Maps or disable it in Android Auto
